# How to debug delivery status of AWS SNS from message ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I use AWS for sending emails and SMS messages. I know about failed email messages because of the mailer-daemon returned email. Recently, I stopped receiving SMS messages on my text phone, even though the code runs without a problem and I get a message ID for the SMS message. The code publishes an SMS directly to a phone, not to a topic. The Python code is:

```py
import botocore
import boto3

def send_text(message):
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='sms')
    try:
        resource = boto3.resource('sns', region_name="eu-west-1")
        response = resource.meta.client.publish(
            PhoneNumber=PHONE, Message=message)
        message_id = response['MessageId']
        print("Published message with text: '%s', id = '%s'." % (message, message_id))
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError:
        print("Couldn't publish message.")
        raise
```

and the log shows:

```
Published message with text: '..', id = 'f4494169-...'.
```

I checked the [CloudWatch console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) for the relevant region (eu-west-1) and do not see any metrics at all, either for SES or SNS. The [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/) explain how to monitor publishing to topics, not for direct messages to phones.

How can I debug the SMS sending and check the delivery status with the message ID?

### update

I now see a log group in CloudWatch bearing this name:

```
arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:<my AWS id>:log-group:sns/eu-west-1/<my AWS id>/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber:*
```

The log streams show only successful deliveries and not failed deliveries, even though my code shows the same output for a successful and a failed send.

The issue in my case seems correlated with events in Simple Email Service, such as email bounces and resets. Although I don't understand the reason, the problem goes away after a few days.

### second update

I see this graphic on my Console for SNS:

[image: successful and failed sends]

My code shows the same result for both successful and failed sends. The SMS messages are already marked as critical (as opposed to transactional). I did not have events in SES that triggered these failed sends, unlike in previous occurrences, and I do not see links to more information about the failures. How can I debug the reason for failed delivery?

Comment: Did you activate [SNS delivery status logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No, that page gives directions when publishing to topics and in my case I am sending directly to a phone number.

Comment: Ah, that is true! I can't see a way to obtain Delivery Status Logging for directly-sent (not via Topic) messages. I sent a few messages to an intentionally-incorrect number and they all came back with a similar response to a correct phone number. Perhaps you'll need to subscribe yourself to a topic and turn on Delivery Status Logging just to debug this situation. The most common cause I have seen of non-delivery has to do with using Short Codes in countries that have restrictions. Let us know how you go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delivery status logging can be enabled for SMS direct publishes as well. Please see [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html) for instructions on how to do so. This setting will emit logs for *all* SMS sent from your account in the region irregardless of whether they were published through a topic or directly.

Read the [details for setting up correctly](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/). The same docs explain the monitoring of the logs:

> 1. Open the [Amazon CloudWatch console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/).
> 2. On the navigation pane, expand Logs, and then choose Log groups.

Be sure to select the right region at the top right. The graph you showed in your second update is from Amazon SNS; the logs with error messages are on CloudWatch. There you see a log group such as:

```
sns/eu-west-1/<your ID>/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber/Failure
```

Click on it and you will see several "Log streams". Click on one and you'll see a message such as this one:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "<some ID>",
        "timestamp": "2021-11-24 09:00:25.193"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "destination": "+100000000",
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "providerResponse": "No quota left for account",
        "dwellTimeMs": 70
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

In this case, SNS has a $1/month default quota and you'd have to request an increase with a detailed use case.

Comment: I enabled it and I see only 10% success rate. To debug the reason, do I need to enable `Amazon S3 bucket name for usage reports` or `IAM role for successful and failed deliveries`?

Comment: If you configure this in the console (e.g. at https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v3/home?region=us-east-1#/mobile/text-messaging/edit-preferences - change to your chosen region), you can set it to emit logs for 100% of successful deliveries. You will need an IAM role configured for this. There is an option to create a role right there on the page as well.

Comment: I followed these steps, thanks. But I couldn't find on [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) how to access the content of the ARN. And would it also have the delivery status for the failed messages?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by accessing the content of the ARN? To answer your second question, yes all failed messages will generate logs.

Comment: Thanks! I set up the logs to a specific ARN. Can you point me in the direction of how to read the logs now that they are in that ARN?

Comment: Here's an explanation on how to view CloudWatch log data: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html#ViewingLogData. If the IAM role is set up correctly on the SNS console (there is also an option to have it automatically generated for you), you should have a couple of log groups with traces in them after sending a few SMS.

Comment: Yes, that seems the right place. But I see "No log groups". I checked that the region is the same as the code for sending the SMS and for setting up the text messaging preferences. I signed in as root user, which I assume should encompass all IAM roles. I could not sign in as the IAM role, though.

Comment: Is that still the case? Sometimes logs may take some time to arrive. Did you use the automatic role generator to set up the role? The fastest way to generate a log message is to attempt to send a SMS to a number you know doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I still see "No log groups" and I used the automatic role generator when I set up the logs. I send myself an SMS every day and I haven't received it in 2 weeks, so I should see a failure or success log. I'll check again in a few days.

Comment: It sounds like you have everything set up correctly. I'd suggest submitting a support case to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm on the basic plan with no tech support, so I'll wait until I go to a new plan to submit a support case.

Comment: Recently I started having problems with SMS deliveries again. It seems that delivery logging is enabled now but I can't find the reason. I edited the question. Could you have another look?

Comment: It sounds like SMS delivery status logs aren't set up correctly if you aren't receiving logs explaining the failure. Details for setting this up are available here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/. If you attempt to send an SMS to e.g. `+10000000000`, you should see a delivery failure log arriving to your `sns/$REGION/$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber/Failure` log group within a minute or two.

Comment: Thank you. I had conflated the SNS console and the CloudWatch console, which shows the logs with errors. I now see the logs with the latest reason being over-quota. The problem "went away after a few days" probably because the month ended and a fresh quota started. I added details to your answer and accepted it.