Sending SMS messages through SNS on AWS and I never seem to get the response
I have a requirement to send a SMS to a phone number.  This is a phone that we have control of and is not a customer. Im struggling because a lot of the tutorials are targetted for marketing and AWS pinpoint.  Im trying to use SNS to send the message.
Im doing the following command.
aws sns publish --phone-number +1xxxxxxxxxx --message 'SUccess!'

I get a response like so
{
"MessageId": "54f30704-16db-5e40-8b10-yyyyyyyyyyyy"
}
And I never get the message on the phone. Not even sure where to look for why its failing. Also there is a mention of originator numbers.  Can I use my company number or does it also have to be SMS capable.
If you know of a tutorial to get started that is not out of date then I would appreciate that.

Are you looking for a tutorial on how to send a CLI command to SNS?

More like Im trying to get sns to send a SMS message.

Might something similar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68140850/how-to-debug-delivery-status-of-aws-sns-from-message-id
also messages get blocked @ operator level if pone number has DND  type services enabled
